# Revoke refresh token after login keycloak

Tags: jwt, keycloak

I am using Keycloak to secure my microservices. I am getting access and refresh tokens by login and password:

```
http://localhost:8088/auth/realms/keep-list/protocol/openid-connect/token
client_id:<your_client_id>
username:<your_username>
password:<your_password>
grant_type:password
```

And to get new access and refresh tokens:

```
http://localhost:8088/auth/realms/keep-list/protocol/openid-connect/token
{
    'client_id': 'your_client_id',
    'refresh_token': refresh_token_from_previous_request,
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token'
}
```

How I can revoke older refresh token after getting new one by login and password?
It needs if someone stole my refresh token and got new access and refresh tokens, user will see that refresh token already used(resuse refresh=0). And I want that after new authorization by login pass, stoled token will revoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try call this endpoint to revoke an access token using a post:

{serverName}/auth/realms/{realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/revoke

Comment: And how does one pass refresh token to it? What are the parameters?

Comment: Make a request to: auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token
{realm}: The name of your Keycloak realm.

And in grant_type: Set this parameter to refresh_token.

In refresh_token: Include the refresh token obtained during the initial authentication process.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me with Keycloak version 22.0.3, using Postman.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GSSO.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).